# Trivialising cover for étale morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Let $f:Y \to X$ be a finite étale morphism of smooth and proper schemes over a field $k$ (not necessarily separable closed).

> Is there a *geometrically connected* étale cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ which trivializes $Y$, i.e. $Y \times_k U_i$ is the disjoint union of copies of $U_i$?

EDIT: it seems that, for general $k$, the above is not necessarily true. I have a couple of follow-up questions:

> - If $k = k^{sep}$, is there a positive answer to my original question?
> - Is there a *connected* étale cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ which  trivializes $Y$, for a general $k$?

Comment: What about when $X$ is the spectrum of a field $k$? The only etale covers are of the form $\text{Spec}(L)$ for $L/K$ finite separable. But the only such geometrically connected such scheme is $\text{Spec}(K)$ itself.

Comment: $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$ is connected, as a scheme over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{R})$, but when you base change to the alg. closure of $\mathbb{R}$ it becomes two points. In fact, $\text{Spec}(L)$ will have $[L:K]$ many discrete points in base change to the alg. closure of $K$. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I get your point. Is the statement true if we take $k = k^{sep}$?